# Vue strap get value from select

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-strap, vue-select

I have problem. Can't get value from select using vue strap select.

My html code:

```html
<bs-select 
  v-model="select.value" 
  :options="select.options" 
  options-value="val" 
  justified 
  close-on-select 
  placeholder="Chose action" 
  @change="contract_corresponds_activity"
></bs-select>
```

I tried :value.sync except v-model as well.

My js code:

```js
import {input, checkbox, select, option} from 'vue-strap'
export default {
components: {
  'bs-select': select,
},
data () {
  return {
select: {
      options: [
        {val: 0, label: 'unknown'},
        {val: 1, label: 'plus 1'},
        {val: 2, label: 'plus 2'},
        {val: 4, label: 'plus 4'},
        {val: 6, label: 'plus 6'}
      ],
      value: ''
    }
},
methods: {
some_function () {
    alert(this.select.value)
    axios.post(this.api_url + this.$route.params.id + '/domgmt', { value: this.select.value
    }).then(response => {
      this.update_form_data(response.data)
    }).catch(error => {
      this.errors = error.response.data.errors
    })
  }
}
```

This code gave me select option, but i cant save it to variable value. My post request is empty string, same as my alert gives me nothing. My goal is to send value: 1, 2, 4, 6 or 0.

Comment: the docs use `:value.sync="select.value"` and not v-model

Comment: i tried :value.sync, no changes, value is still empty string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that i should add parametr to on change event so code will look like:

```
 some_function (value) {
    alert(value)
    axios.post(this.api_url + this.$route.params.id + '/domgmt', { value: value
    }).then(response => {
      this.update_form_data(response.data)
    }).catch(error => {
      this.errors = error.response.data.errors
    })
  }
```

In that case it will show what i've clicked just now